# How to fix?: Image disappears in Safari, when I'm using fabric js image filters

Tags: javascript, image, filter, safari, fabricjs

I'm programming an application where people can upload images. The images appear in a canvas and then the user can click buttons with image filters, so the image in the canvas changes brightness, contrast, saturation and so on. I'm using Fabric Js. You can see the javascript of a noise filter below. This code works fine in IE and Chrome, but it doesn't work in Safari 11.0.3. There, when I click on the buttons, the image turns transparent / disappears. What am I doing wrong? Do I miss something?

```
$("#noise").click(function () {
                var filter = new fabric.Image.filters.Noise({
                    noise: 700
                });
                var obj = canvas.getActiveObject();
                obj.filters.push(filter);
                obj.applyFilters();
                canvas.renderAll();
            });
```

EDIT: Seems like the images were too big! With smaller images the code is running fine in Safari.

Comment: Check and test this [demo](http://fabricjs.com/image-filters) in safari with Noise filter

Comment: Hello! The demo version works fine. I figured it out! Turned out, my images were too large, I think! With smaller images the code is working in Safari.